# regex fails to match

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, cygwin

my pattern seems to match external regex tester but my program fails. what's wrong with my code ?
I would appreciate any comments

my code:

```
std::smatch matches;

s = "y=a^b,z=(y+76),k=(z|p)";

for (int t=0; t<4; t++) { 

  try {
    std::regex  expr ( "((\\w+)=\\((\\w+)([\\|&\\^\\+\\-\\*])(\\w+)\\))" , regex_constants::extended );    // regex::extended|regex_constants::basic 


    std::regex_match(s, matches, expr);

    if ( matches.empty() ) puts ("No Match !");
```

[image]

Comment: **Pro-tip:** regex101 has a feature to save regexes and generate a link so you can share it. Please use that feature so we can easily fiddle and improve your regex. For example, you could use a character class instead of a group `[/*^&+-]` which is slightly elegant and shorter. That said, define "program fails". Does it compile? It doesn't match? Etc...

Comment: link is http://regex101.com/r/rZ9iV1/1

Comment: yes, it compiles . it fails at run time with regex_error
error_escape: invalid escape character or trailing escape

Comment: $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 5):

First, GCC did not support `<regex>` until 4.9, you will have to upgrade or switch to another compiler (clang or MSVC, for example) or use [boost.regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Second, [regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) attempts to match the entire string, it will fail. You need [regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) or [regex_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)

Third, your regex is not a valid POSIX ERE (at least according to libc++ and gcc 4.9), just drop the regex_constants:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::smatch matches;
    std::string s = "y=a^b,z=(y+76),k=(z|p)";
    std::regex  expr(R"((\w+)=\((\w+)([|&^+*-])(\w+)\))"); // simplified a bit

    for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), expr);
             it != std::sregex_iterator();
           ++it)
    {
         std::cout << "Found a match: " << it->str() << "\n";
         std::smatch m = *it;

         std::cout << "prefix=[" << m.prefix() << "]\n";
         for(std::size_t n = 0; n < m.size(); ++n)
                 std::cout << "   m[" << n << "]=[" << m[n] << "]\n";
         std::cout << "suffix=[" << m.suffix() << "]\n";
    }
}
```

online demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/559d3bca554517c6

Comment: thanks a lot. Is there clang on winows/cygwin/mingw ? I checked cygwin but they have g++ 4.8 (I don't know the schedule for 4.9) In the past I used pcre .. seems to me it is my best shot for now